# Need help writing tests for SASS styles in Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, sass, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

## Summarize the problem

### To begin with

To build a custom React components library, I've followed this guide ([Building a React Components Library](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-react-components-library-f5a390d5973d)). The author uses react-styleguided along with emotion for styling, but I've found myself being more prolific with SASS, which I know already.

### Setup

After some research I've set Babel and Styleguided's webpack to work with SASS. However, Jest would return failed tests because of `@import` rules in my `*.*sass` files.

This blog post here ([Testing React components with Jest and Enzyme](https://blog.sapegin.me/all/react-jest/)) helped me to figure out how I would do it work and, after a little work, I got all functional tests so far.

### The "problem"

But I'm not finding any proper documentation on "how to write styling tests for SASS". Actually, I'm not even able to understand how I could work it out, since testing components is a new thing for me. This is my first React components library.

Is there any resource I could reach to learn about it?

Comment: You seem to confuse there something a little ;). Why would you test a components styling? `Jest` is a *Javascript* Testing Framwork.

Comment: I might be. Actually, in the original guide I linked above, there's some style testing, but CSS-in-JS one. I thought that I could elaborate some styling tests for these components, but it seems to be unnecessary.